# Sharepoint Search 2013: Create new result type for local people result

Tags: search, 2013, search-results, display-template

I have created a new display template for local people search and it's working perfectly.

I wanted to create a result type for local people search to use my custom display template but it's using the default person display template. Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware the Display Template is configured on the actual search landing page.  If you reconfigure the web part on the peopleresults.aspx page to use the custom display template it should render as you desire.

If you want to be able to render using both the default people display template and the custom one you created, then you simply need to result pages.

Update:

To configure a Result Type so that the changes will also be reflected on the regular Results.aspx page:

1. Navigate to the Site Settings Page
2. Under the Search category, select the Result Types link
3. Select the New Result Type option
4. Give it a name
5. For the source, select Local People Results
6. Select your Display Template
7. Click the save button

Comment: Yeah my custom display template is working in peopleresults.aspx. But in results.aspx page if we searh for people it'll display people result. In that case it's not using my custom template for that I wanted to create a result type. So it will use my custom template in all the result pages. Can you help me on creating a result type for people search??

Answer (score -1):

Just came across this article: http://richardstk.wordpress.com/2013/04/09/extend-sharepoint-2013-people-search-using-business-connectivity-services-part-4/